# UV unwrap / Cannot link image to face or any other object

Tags: uv

I tried various tutorials for UV unwrapping following every single step.
In UV Editing window I can open image but it will never actually link to the object. It always remains a dark grey. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
[image: Globe]

Comment: You need to add a material with the texture driving the color value

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise You do not have to add a material to get the texture to appear in textured view.

Comment: No, not in texture view. It just needs to be unwrapped, right?

Comment: Actually, not. You may notice that Blender Render (not Cycles) is used as renderer. In this case you may see the texture in Textured node on the mesh that wasn't unwrapped - http://i.imgur.com/SS5jev7.jpg. (The mesh is not unwrapped). Actual problem for me remains unkonwn. I would import everything from this scene to a new one and try again

Comment: Fro cycles watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U